# How to set fontStyle for each item in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

**I have a ArrayList of fonts and each item have a "text" written in a textview so I'm trying to do set a different font style for each item in a Recyclerview. How to set font style for each item.**

```
//It's My Adapter class

public class FontAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FontAdapter.FontViewHolder>
 {
ArrayList<FontModel> fontModelArrayList;
Context context;
int row_index=-1;

public FontAdapter(ArrayList<FontModel> fontModelArrayList, Context context) {
    this.fontModelArrayList = fontModelArrayList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
@NonNull
public FontViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    context= parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View fontView= layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.font_list_item,parent,false);
    return new FontViewHolder(fontView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FontAdapter.FontViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    FontModel fontModel=fontModelArrayList.get(position);

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
     row_index=position;
     notifyDataSetChanged();
 });

    // for setting the background
    // when you selected
    if(row_index==position){
        holder.fontLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.font_background_item2);
        holder.fontTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0F393B"));
    }
    else
    {
        holder.fontLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.font_background_item);
        holder.fontTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF"));
    }
 }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
 return fontModelArrayList.size();
}

public static class FontViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
   TextView fontTextView;
   LinearLayout fontLayout;
    public FontViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        fontTextView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.fontStyleTextView);
        fontLayout= itemView.findViewById(R.id.fontItemLinearLayout);
    }
 }
```

}

And **I'm put the all font style in a font folder like this.
font/arabic.ttf** and so on. How to set diffrent font style for each items.

```
 public static ArrayList<FontModel> getAllFonts(){
    ArrayList<FontModel> listOfFonts =new ArrayList<>();
    listOfFonts.add(new FontModel(R.font.arabic));
     ..
     ..
     ..
     ..        
    so on
    return listOfFonts;
}
```

Comment: show what you have already got. no one will wirte for you whole adapter sample in a case, when you just need a hint where to place `setTypeface` method call...

Comment: @snachmsm I'm updated the code please check this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add some typeface setting code on the end of `onBindViewHolder`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FontAdapter.FontViewHolder holder, int position) {
    FontModel fontModel = fontModelArrayList.get(position);

    // current code

    Context ctx = holder.itemView.getContext();
    Typeface typeface = ctx.getResources().getFont(fontModel.getFontResourceId());
    //or
    Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(ctx, fontModel.getFontResourceId());
    fontTextView.setTypeface(typeface);
}
```